# Relocate error labels using jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So I'm using [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and have managed (despite some out of date documentation) to get a group of required radio boxes working. The problem is the plugin is appending the error label directly after the first radio (the first of that group that has the required class).

With this in mind is it possible to set a custom location for each error label?

For reference this is the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td width="200">
        <label>Title2 *</label>
    </td>
    <td width="505">
>>>     <label><input type="radio" class="required" name="Title2" value="Mr" /> <!-- ERROR APPEARS HERE -->Mr</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="required" name="Title2" value="Miss" />Miss</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="required" name="Title2" value="Mrs" />Mrs</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="required" name="Title2" value="Ms" />Ms</label>
        <!-- I WANT ERROR LABEL HERE -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Scroll across on the line marked `>>>` and you'll see the comment that shows there the plugin is putting the error label, just before the closing `</td>` you'll see where I want the label to go.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding the label tag where you want:

```
<label class="error" for="Title2" generated="true"></label>
```

The plugin will use this tag to display error

Comment: Thanks @Karan, I had tried this but neglected to put the title in, D'oh! :D

Comment: Docs are here http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/ add anchor Error message display

Answer (score 0):

why can't you put css something like

```
span.error{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

This will put your spans into right hand side and it will look good too.
if you are steel confused put your code into jsfiddle. i will do that there.

or checkout this example of how to put error containers
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't use CSS in this instance. And whilst I'm going to accept Karan's answer I didn't know about the error container, so +1 for that.